# What is the difference of the unapply function in pattern matching and in a partial function

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have an extractor which extracts an object from a string.

```
case class ItemStructure(id: String, data: String)
object ItemStructure {
  def unapply(str: String): Option[ItemStructure] = {
    str.split('-').toList match {
      case List(id, data) => Some(ItemStructure(id, data))
      case _              => None
    }
  }
}
```

If I try to use this extractor in a pattern matching, then all works as expected.

```
"" match {
  case ItemStructure(item) =>
}
```

It also works in a pattern matching anonymous function.

```
Option("").map {
  case ItemStructure(item) => 
}
```

Now, if I try to use this extractor in a partial function, the compiler fails with the message: cannot resolve overloaded unapply

```
val func: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
  case ItemStructure(item) =>
}
```

If I rename the companion object where the unapply function is located then all works as expected.

Could someone explain why the extract doesn't work if it's located in the companion object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two `ItemStructure.unapply` methods: The one created by the case class and the one you created yourself. The former takes an argument of type `ItemStructure` and the latter takes an argument of type `String`.

In your first two examples the type of the matched object is `String`, so only the second `unapply` method can be applied and there's no ambiguity. But in the last example both `unapply` methods would qualify, so Scala does not know which one to use.

If you put your `unapply` method somewhere else than the companion object, there's no longer two `unapply` methods - only yours (because the other one still lives in the companion object). So that resolves the ambiguity: `ItemStructure.unapply` clearly refers to the auto-generated `unapply` and `NewName.unapply` clearly refers to your.

Comment: I couldn't understand how the last example fits for the both of unapply methods. Can you also explain it?

Comment: @fcat If the type is String, `unapply(ItemStructure)` can never match, so doesn't need to be considered. If the type is `ItemStructure`, `unapply(String)` can never match. If the type is `Any`, both can match because an `Any` could be an `ItemStructure` or it could be a `String`.

Comment: Ok, I blind to see the last one's type is `Any`. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

With `Any` as result type Compiler is not able to figure out where should it take the unapply function from. Your `unappl`y defines only behaviour for `String` type.

This would work though:

```
val func: PartialFunction[String, Unit] = {
  case ItemStructure(item) =>
}
```

Otherwise try defining unapply function that takes the type `Any`.

Comment: I've accepted the answer from @sepp2k because it's more detailed.